# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Double tap with two fingers not eating in Minecraft

Tags: linux, ubuntu, touchpad, minecraft

In my laptop's touchpad double tap with two fingers only work single time in Minecraft as well as on desktop/Home i.e single right-click , but in Minecraft it do not hold with two finger double tap or even holding with two fingers, i can't eat my cooked food.
Although I have gnome tweaks installed.